# Orgmode: Show number of children under heading

Tags: org-mode

I have a heading in my orgmode file. It is automatically updated periodically with new children. I want the heading line to show the number of children.

So if I have one child it would say something like `(1)`

```
* Heading (1)
** Subheading
```

After it gets updated with another subheading the number should automatically be changed to `(2)`

```
* Heading (2)
** Subheading
** A new added subheading
```

I want it to do this because the toplevel heading will normally be collapsed. I want to be able to see if any new children were added to it without having to expand it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's most similar to what you're searching are called statistics cookies. They're described at the end of [this page in the manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html). At first meant for lists, but that can also count headlines. Just put `[/]` at the end of your header, like so :

```
* Main header [/]
** sub-header 1
** sub-header 2
** sub-header 3
```

And press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on the cookie to update it (make it update its count). What you **do need to add** to what you describe to be your use-case is `TODO` keywords to your headers, because *what the cookie will count is how many are done over how many are to do*. Therefore I suggest you mark them all as `DONE`, like so :

```
* Main header [3/3]
** DONE sub-header 1
** DONE sub-header 2
** DONE sub-header 3
```

Then, the counter will show you what you want.

You could probably adapt these cookies' code to meet your precise needs.

Comment: Yup that does it. All I really need is the denominator but it's not that much of an issue. I always though this only worked for lists!