# Emacs ordered lists in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to create nesting ordered lists in org-mode:

```
1. task-1
1.1. task-1-1
1.2. task-1-2
1.2.1. task-1-2-1
```

With the ability to hide them with tab and attach TODO and DONE keywords? Cause it's always handy to know, how many tasks do we have to do and how many are left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is, just go on and nest them, by indenting them a little bit more at each level :

```
* The almighty header
  - item 1
  - item 2
    - item 2.1
    - item 2.2
      - item 2.2.1
    - item 2.3
  - item 3
```

That's all <kbd>tab</kbd>-able.

For keywords and counting, I suppose you're referring to statistic cookies (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372929/1449460)).

Just add [checkbokes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) to your list items (`[ ]` for todo and `[X]` for done), and place a counter (`[/]` or `[%]`) on the heading. Update it with <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.

```
 * The almighty header [1/3]
   - [X] item 1
   - [ ] item 2
     - [X] item 2.1
     - [X] item 2.2
       - [X] item 2.2.1
     - [ ] item 2.3
   - [ ] item 3
```

As is, it counts just the first sub-level, but you can set the `org-hierarchical-todo-statistics` variable if you want it differently.

As for genuine `TODO` keywords for list items, as far as I know, that's just a big **NO** : *if you need them, use headers instead of lists*, or [inlinetasks](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob;f=lisp/org-inlinetask.el;h=01f861e611aee4c24fcf7184ea191962be83be70;hb=HEAD).